# Pyspark cassandra connector NoclassDefFoundError, util/logging

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I downloaded the `spark-cassandra-connector_3.12-3.2.0.jar` and put in `/apache-spark/3.2.1/libexec/jars` folders.

Calling this jar in conf like:

```py
conf=SparkConf().setAppName("d").setMasetMaster("local")
   .set("spark.driver.extraClassPath",
        "jarPath/spark-cassandra-connector_3.12-3.2.0.jar")
```

Querying caasandra but getting below error, please suggest

```
**Py4j.protocol.PyJJavaError: An error occurred while calling o114.load.
:Java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/spark/connector/util/logging**
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that this jar doesn't contain all necessary dependencies.   Second problem is that you're using incorrect configuration property.

To fix it you have two choices:

1. You use `spark.jars.packages` configuration property (or `--packages` in the command-line) with value `com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.12:3.2.0` as described in the [docs](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/0_quick_start.md).  This will fetch the jar + necessary dependencies
2. You instead download the [spark-cassandra-connector-assembly](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.datastax.spark/spark-cassandra-connector-assembly) jar that includes all dependencies and use it with `spark.jars` configuration property (or `--jars` in the command-line).

P.S. See Spark docs about [configuration properties](https://spark.jars).

Comment: I did as per ur suggestion(point 2, adding --jar and inclusing in driver and executire class path), I still am running into issues, same error as I earlier stated. Any suggestions, will really appreciate

Comment: I believe that you may construct SparkSession incorrectly, or something like that

Comment: I could connect to maven repo. Log shows artifacts retrieved but none downloaded. And also getting connection refused error. How do I check if package was downloaded? I checked spark local jar folder, but timestamp wasn't updated. So does that mean it failed to download? @Alex Ott

Comment: Package is downloaded only in option 1. Connection refused means that you don’t have correct host configuration, but at least it means that library is loaded correctly. Artifacts are downloaded into .ivy folder of your home directory